# How to isolate messages using postMessage as a serializer?

Tags: javascript, serialization

Using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to serialize and deserialize objects has subtle problems such as date objects being serialized as strings and then coming out on the other side as strings rather than date objects. I've tried using `postMessage` instead which has the benefit of producing 1:1 results, but I'm worried about other handlers eaves dropping on the messages. I've considered writing my own serializer/deserializer, but would prefer native browser capabilities.

Is there a way to use `postMessage` like a serializer, without having to worry about eavesdropping?

*NOTE: I don't care about eavesdropping using dev tools. My app is loading plugin like modules and I want to make sure those aren't able to eavesdrop on messages that are for other modules.*

Comment: Your question is quite long. If you're really only interested in the serializing part, consider changing the title and reducing the question's body. That would make it easier for others (googlers) to judge whether the Q&A describes their case.

Comment: Done, hope that improves the question. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can supply a custom JSON parser/stringifier to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var serialized = JSON.stringify(obj, /*func*/replacer);
var deserialized = JSON.parse(serialized, /*func*/reviver);
```

In addition to the custom reviver, you can also define a `toJSON` method on the object which is going to be serialized. This method receives one argument: the key's name <sup>indexes in arrays, property names in objects</sup>, if applicable.

```
// Examples of a serializing a function
var dummyFunction = function() {return 'hey';};

Function.prototype.toJSON = function(key) {
    'use strict';
    return this.toString();
};
JSON.stringify(dummyFunction);
// Method 2:
var replacer = function(/*string*/key, /*any*/value, /*boolean*/pretty_print) {
    if (typeof value == 'function') return value.toString();
    return value;
};
JSON.stringify(dummyFunction, replacer);
// >>> "function () {\n    return \"hey\";\n}"
// Result of the previous, stored in a variable
var result =  '"function () {\\n    return \\"hey\\";\\n}"';

// Reviver example
// Note: Just an example. Do not use it without modification in production code,
// Because the pattern can easily be misguided: "function(){}alert('Evil');x={}"
// Even if you do not mind, at least add a try-catch block inside
//   `if (func)`, so that a malformed function does not break the reviver
JSON.parse(result, function(/*string*/key, /*string*/value) {
    var func = /^\s*function\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s\{([\S\s]*)}$/.exec(value);
    if (func) {
        // Note: Function( .. ) is equivalent to new Function( .. )
        var args = func[1].match(/[^,\s]+/g); // <-- Parameters
        // Function body:
        if (args === null) args = [func[2]];
        else args.unshift(func[2]);
        return Function.apply(null, args);
    }
    return value;
});
```

Here's a JSPerf comparison of **native parsing vs parsing with a reviver: http://jsperf.com/json-reviver**. It shows that a custom reviver which does nothing special is two times slower, and that a reviver with expensive functionality is significantly slower.
However, when the last method is compared to a weaker method using native JSON and "manual conversion", then the differences seems to be neglected.
Note: Only a single value is benchmarked. Make sure to create a custom benchmark for your own (specific) case, because it's impossible to create one benchmark which represents every possible case.

I have created a [JSPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-tojson) which checks the impact of `.toJSON`. To isolate noise, I've created a test case based on the `Date` object. A custom function with several function calls is just two times slower than a native [`Date.prototype.toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON).

Comment: I never read the MDN docs about JSON when they came out with it and so I never knew about the second parameter. Thanks. =)

Comment: I had missed these in the docs, clearly I was skimming. This may well be good enough, although I'm slightly worried about the performance aspect. Would love to hear your thoughts on that.

Comment: @macke Added example of a custom replacer, reviver and `MyObject.prototype.toJSON` + two benchmarks.

Comment: @macke And: If the apps are at the same page as yours, there is no way to prevent eavesdropping. Anything you create to prevent this can be countered, since the apps have to same permissions and object access as your page. Although `postMessage` is the way to pass data between frames, you could also use `localStorage` to pass data between the same domain. Your own page can be notified of a change through `postMessage`, or a frame refresh event (for example).

Comment: Right, so I probably worded my question poorly. Preventing eavesdropping fully and making this 100% secure is not the goal, but on the other hand I don't want it to be convenient to eavesdrop either. I consider `window.addEventListener("message", myFunc)` to be much too convenient a way, and if I can make that considerably more difficult without sacrificing too much, I'd prefer that. I think the method you propose will do it, so I'll accept your answer. Many thanks for the excellent feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `postMessage`, you could use a specific cloning method.

I use this one :

```
function goclone(source) {
    if ($.isArray(source)) {
        var clone = [];
        for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
            if (source[i]) clone[i] = goclone(source[i]);
        }
        return clone;
    } else if (typeof(source)=="object") {
        var clone = {};
        for (var prop in source) {
            if (source[prop]) {
                clone[prop] = goclone(source[prop]);
            }
        }
        return clone;
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}
```

It doesn't copy the prototype, functions, and so, on and ignores `null`/`NaN` fields.

If you don't want to use jquery, you could code yourself a `isArray` function like this

```
function isArray(obj) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]':
}
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion, and I may well go down the custom route. However, I'd prefer native browser capabilities so I'm looking into that first.

Answer (score 1):

DOM events level 2 can be canceled by any event handler that calls the `stopPropagation` method of the event object it's handling. If you make sure that your event handler is the first one on the page (essentially by making sure that your script tags are the first ones on the page) then you can call `stopPropagation` to prevent other code from eavesdropping on your messages. You may also do this on a selective basis to make sure that only your events are filtered out.

So essentially you'll be doing this:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

    if (data.secret === "my event and not anyone else's") {
        // do something
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}, false);
```

Note however that people can still use tools like greasemonkey to intercept your events. On the web you can never be sure. JavaScript is an open source language. Hope this helps though.

Comment: This is how I've been doing it so far, but unfortunately I can't guarantee the order by which handlers are added. Even if I were, I think the specification doesn't actually guarantee the order in which handlers are fired, so it doesn't matter in which order they were added. I guess most (all?) browsers fire the handlers in the order they were added so in practice it probably wouldn't matter. But I'd rather find a more stable solution.

Comment: From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic): "Although all EventListeners on the EventTarget are guaranteed to be triggered by any event which is received by that EventTarget, no specification is made as to the order in which they will receive the event with regards to the other EventListeners on the EventTarget"